# Transformation law of interacting potential in non-inertial frame?

Tags: reference-frames, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I haven't seen this addressed in most lecture notes but how does the interacting potential of (say) the Klein-Gordon equation transform in a non-inertial frame? (Feel free to answer more generally as well)

$$ (\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2 +m^2) \psi + \underbrace{\lambda \psi^3}_{\text{interacting field}} = 0 $$

Comment: It’s a scalar field, so nothing nontrivial happens!

Comment: Insert *facepalm* here

Answer (score 1):

Like knzhou said, this is a scalar field, so nothing happens when you transform to a non-inertial frame.